# Error layout.jade

Tags: node.js, pug

I'm working on `node.js` project using (mysql, express, jade).
I don't know exactly what is the problem.
This is the results when I'm trying to run the project

> Error: C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\views\site\layout.jade:20 18| form(action='/login', method='post').navbar-form.navbar-right 19| div.form-group > 20| input(type='text', placeholder='email', name='email').form-control  21| div(style='margin-left: 5px;').form-group 22| input(type='password', placeholder='password', name='password').form-control 23| button(type='submit', style='margin-left: 5px;').btn.btn-success Sign in unexpected text at Object.Lexer.fail (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:887:11) at Object.Lexer.next (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:947:15) at Object.Lexer.lookahead (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\lexer.js:113:46) at Parser.lookahead (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:102:23) at Parser.peek (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:79:17) at Parser.tag (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:773:22) at Parser.parseTag (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:759:17) at Parser.parseExpr (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:211:21) at Parser.block (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:729:25) at Parser.tag (C:\Users\jean\Desktop\twitter\node_modules\jade\lib\parser.js:838:24)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got ' > ' on line 20

If your intention is to display the angle bracket then you should place a pipe in front of it
Something like

```
div.form-group 
   | >
   input(type='text', placeholder='email', name='email').form-control
```

Comment: This the line 20: form(action='/login', method='post').navbar-form.navbar-right
      div.form-group
       input(type='text', placeholder='email', name='email').form-control